# How to click link

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I am new to cucumber automation testing. Need your help.  How to click this link whose value is "Add all"?

```
   <div class="actions ui-header ui-helper-clearfix">
   <a href="#" class="add-all btnadd" style="display: block; ">Add all</a>
   </div>
```

What i have tried is not working for me:

```
  if(page.find("a")[:href] == "add all")
    click_on("Add all")
  end
```

error getting:
    `Ambiguous match, found 340 elements matching css "a" (Capybara::Ambiguous)
           ./features/step_definitions/Raffles_Winner.rb:223:in /^Editing newly added 
             raffle$/'`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `click_link('Add all')` should do the trick.

You can checkout this [Cheat Sheet](https://gist.github.com/zhengjia/428105) for more references on capybara.

Comment: Thanx for answering . But total four 'Add all' exists in my page .

Comment: OK so you need to add an id to your link and call ``click_link('link_id')``

Comment: This cheatsheet is quiet obsolete as you can see [in this comment that I left](https://gist.github.com/zhengjia/428105#comment-840302) so I think it's bad to link to it

Comment: It's possible to select a link not only by id but also using many other selector types like `:css` or `:xpath`. Even `:link` selector (and thus `click_link` method) supports not only id and text [but also title and image alt attribute](https://github.com/jnicklas/xpath/blob/master/lib/xpath/html.rb#L11). So it's incorrect to say that OP **needs** to add an id to his link

Comment: Taking a look at [the official documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#clicking-links-and-buttons) about links, adding an id to the link still seems like the easiest way to achieve what @PathFinder is trying to do. Sure, they are other ways to do it but the id is still the easiest one.